# Google Cloud Pub/Sub with ordering keys & multiple consumers on same subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

A question on the behaviour of Cloud Pub/Sub:
Assuming I have a topic with message ordering, and a subscription handling message ordering.
if I have more than one consumer for the subscription, is there a way to ensure the same consumer always gets the messages for the same ordering key?
I’m basically trying to work out if similar parallelism behaviour as with Kafka topic partitions is possible, in order to be able to have stateful consumers handling all messages for some key.

Comment: AFAIK, it's the default behavior of PubSub with ordering key and multiple subscriber: the same subscriber will receive all the message of the same ordering key, in order. I had difficulties to find that in the doc, here something close: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull

Comment: On the [Pub/Sub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery), you will find that every subscription will receive the message from the topic at least one. To add to guiallaume comment, you can get more detail about ordering [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-pub-sub-ordered-delivery-1e4181f60bc8, enable "Message ordering" on the subscription and set the `OrderingKey` pubsub metadata tag when publishing messages will route messages to the same subscriber in sequence for the same `OrderingKey`.

```
Affinity: If there are messages with an ordering key outstanding to a
streaming pull subscriber, then additional messages that are delivered 
are sent to that same subscriber. If no messages are currently outstanding
for an ordering key, the service delivers messages to the last subscriber 
to receive messages for that key on a best-effort basis.
```